# suEXEC queries www-data when trying to execute a script as userXYZ

Tags: php, apache2, suexec

I am setting up a suexec environment with Apache2 and PHP 7.0 with FastCGI.

I have installed everything the normal way

```
Aptitude install libapache2-mod-fcgid apache2-suexec-custom
A2enmod suexec
```

My server has following structure:

- There are users who have their websites in /home/*username*/public_html/ (linux user "*username*")
- and there is a main website which has its docroot in /data/www/ (user "homepage").

SuEXEC works so far, but there is a major problem: for some reason, suEXEC queries /etc/apache2/suexec/www-data instead of /etc/apache2/suexec/username , therefore I can only have my website at /data working, or the websites at /home working, but not both. I do not understand that, since no script on my server is owned by www-data.

/etc/apache2/suexec/www-data (unchanged, since I don't use www-data)

```
/var/www
public_html/cgi-bin
```

/etc/apache2/suexec/homepage

```
/data
www/cgi-bin
```

/etc/apache2/suexec/userXYZ

```
/home/userXYZ
public_html/cgi-bin
```

/data/www/cgi-bin/php-fcgi

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHPRC="/etc/php/7.0/cgi"
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

/home/userXYZ/public_html/cgi-bin/php-fcgi

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHPRC="/etc/php/7.0/cgi"
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/...

```
<Directory /data/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    FCGIWrapper /data/www/cgi-bin/php-fcgi .php
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>

<Directory /home/userXYZ/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    FCGIWrapper /home/userXYZ/public_html/cgi-bin/php-fcgi .php
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/home/userXYZ/public_html"
        SuexecUserGroup userXYZ userXYZ
        ServerName ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/data/www"
        SuexecUserGroup homepage homepage
        ServerName ...
</VirtualHost>
```

So, when I access my main home (/data/www), it does not work since suexec/www-data.conf has its docroot at /var/www . If I change suexec/www-data.conf to /data , then the main homepage works. But then the users websites do not work, since they are located at /home . If I change www-data to /home , then my main homepage does not work, since it has its docroot at /data ...  How can I avoid that suEXEC queries the www-data config, and instead query the correct user config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785740:

> The idea is to be able to have different apache2 processes running as 
>   different users be able to use different suexec configs.

Thus, if apache2 runs under www-data only the file /etc/apache2/suexec/www-data is being considered.